# View Libreoffice Base queries to mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb, libreoffice-base

I'm trying to create a table with a primary key from Libreoffice Base connected to MariaDB.
A standard table with a primary, autogenerated (incrementing I presume) key.

But it fails with this message:

```
Error: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
' PRIMARY KEY  ("ID"))' at line 1
```

Is there a way to view the query LibereOffice sends?

Comment: could you please show create statement.

Comment: No, that's exactly the problem. The LibreOffice Base GUI makes an error, but I can't see the query.

Comment: Could you please enable audit logs or general logs of mariadb to capture exact query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling logging in the database, to table enabled me to see the faulty query.

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```